# Difference between RInside and Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, rinside

I understand RInside allows C++ program to embed R code, while Rcpp enables R code to call C++ functions or library.

Are there other differences and commonalities between RInside and Rcpp? Why RInside has a namespace called Rcpp? Do developers always need both RInside and Rcpp to call R code as a class in Cpp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rcpp](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp):

> The Rcpp package provides R functions and a C++ library facilitating the integration of R and C++.

[RInside](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/rinside):

> The RInside package provides a few classes for seamless embedding of R inside of C++ applications by relying on Rcpp.

So it appears the Rcpp is lower level and facilities the communication between the two languages, not just from R to C++ as you state but communication in both directions.  RInside, on the other hand, is higher level library built on top of Rcpp focused on easy embedding of R into C++.

Comment: Is Rcpp already included in RInside? Let's say I want to embed some R modules in my C++ application, do I need to install both RInside and Rcpp?

Comment: @GTWu, are you installing through CRAN?  If so, RCpp is a [dependency](https://cran.r-project.org/package=RInside) of RInside, install one and you get the other...